# role="presentation" on H1

Tags: html, wai-aria

Using the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Headings</title></head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <section>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>

        <h1 role="presentation">Not Heading 1</h1>
    </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

ChromeVOX announces "Not Heading 1" as a Heading 1

validator.w3.org Warns:
Warning: Consider using the h1 element as a top-level heading only (all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen readers and other tools).

From what I gather from http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#presentation

I thought role="presentation" would remove the semantic value form the h1 element.

Is this the correct expectation from ChromeVox and validator.w3.org?

Comment: Could it be that the validator warns for it *because* ChromeVox ignores the role attribute? It's not an error, so it's not saying that your code is flat out wrong, but says to reconsider due to the behavior of tools looking at it. The warning could be clearer that the issue is with the tool, not your code, but the documentation does say the validator is a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

For elements with no required children (like h1, h2, etc..), any elements nested inside the element with role=presentation **preserve** their semantics.

However for elements with required children (such as ul or table) any required child elements nested inside the element with role=presentation also have their semantics **removed**.

Comment: Yes, the example for this from http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#presentation shows a nested `abbr` which preserves semantics. The `h1` does not preserve semantics.